# printing in new lines python

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, newline, lines

i've made this little thing and i need the output to be, for example, like this:

```
****
*******
**
****
```

But i get the output this way:

```
************
```

Could you help me? Here's the program.

```
import math 
def MakingGraphic(number):
    list = [number]
    graphic = number * '*'
    return(graphic)


list = 0
howmany = int(input("How many numbers will you write?"))
for i in range(0, howmany, 1):
    number = int(input("Write a number "))
    list = list + number
result = MakingGraphic(list)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need that `MakingGraphic`, just use a list to store the strings of "*":

```
In [14]: howmany = int(input("How many numbers will you write?"))
    ...: lines=[]
    ...: for i in range(howmany):
    ...:     number = int(input("Write a number "))
    ...:     lines.append('*'*number)
    ...: print('\n'.join(lines))
```

The issue of your code is, variable "list" is an integer, not a list (**don't** use "list" as a variable name, because it shadows the python builtin type/function `list`, use some name like `lst` instead).

If you want to try function call, you can change your code to:

```
import math 
def MakingGraphic(lst):
    graphic = '\n'.join(number * '*' for number in lst)
    return graphic


lst = []
howmany = int(input("How many numbers will you write?"))
for i in range(0, howmany, 1):
    number = int(input("Write a number "))
    lst.append(number)

result = MakingGraphic(lst)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 3):

add a "\n" to return to next line.
e.g. `result = MakingGraphic(list) + "\n"`

Why do you use a list by the way ?

```
import math 
def MakingGraphic(number):
    return number * '*'

result = ''
howmany = int(input("How many numbers will you write?"))
for i in range(0, howmany, 1):
    number = int(input("Write a number "))
    result += MakeingGraphic(number) + "\n"
print result
```

Answer (score 1):

You could probably print the stars from the function itself instead of returning it. print will add a new line automatically. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes in the code,
but your problem was that you were sending a int not a list with ints:

```
import math 
def MakingGraphic(number):
  graphic = ''
  for n in list:# loop to the list
    graphic += n * '*' + '\n' # the \n adds a line feed
  return(graphic)

list = [] # list
howmany = int(input("How many numbers will you write?"))
for i in range(0, howmany, 1):
   number = int(input("Write a number "))
   list.append(number) # add the number to the list
result = MakingGraphic(list)
print (result)
```